# Input field is not fitting well within a div

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why this input field with margin (at all sides) is not fitting well within that div. I was hoping to see the input with the right margin being shown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>CSS Tests</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="div2">
    <input type="Foobar">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:indianred;
}

.div2 input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image: input with 100% width and margin but not fitting well]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width 100% will set the width to the available space, which in this case is the width of the parent div. Try setting the width to `width: calc(100% - 20px);` (subtract the margin out).

here is a fiddle link to demonstrate https://jsfiddle.net/2vcokm6x/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `width: 100%` on the `input` element does not account for the margin being set. To work around this, you need to subtract `20px` (for both the left and right margin) from the `width`. This can be achieved with `calc()`, as seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: indianred;
}

.div2 input {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div2">
    <input type="Foobar">
  </div>
</body>
```